# Coordinate Issue (Hierarchial Edge Bundles) in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bundle-layout

I'm new to [d3](http://d3js.org/) and I'm just playing around with the hierarchical edge bundle visualization which can be found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/1044242). I'm trying to add further elements to the visualization and therefore I need the coordinates of every node (that means the coordinates where the edge bundle ends).

If I draw a line from (0,0) to the coordinates of a node, the line does not end where the bundle ends. Somehow the coordinates of the node objects have been modified. How can I get their real coordinates?